# Geoserver ImagePyramid/ImageMosaic with Time Dimension

Tags: raster, geoserver, mosaic

I am having trouble setting the time range of image mosaics granules. The problem is, that it would be necessary to set a valid_from and valid_till for each granule - as far as I could see, there is no solution to this problem. It is just possible to display the picture 1-day.  I tried every setting and changed the attributes, but it remains 1- day.

**How to set a time range for an image mosaic?**
**If it is not possible: How to set a time range for the granules of an image mosaic?**

The documentation mentions a reference value and a range in this format:
2001-01-01/2002-03-23

But I couldn't find a way to set it for raster data. Has anybody had an idea?

Comment: Do I understand right? You want to give a time range for each granule, but you can only set a single time?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to add time ranges to granules, only single time is supported.

Comment: Is it possible to set a time range for a layer?

Comment: The Layer gets its time range automatically from the max and min time of the granules. The Time Range "2001-01-01/2002-03-23" is for the WMS request.

Comment: And how can I define the max and min time of the granules?

Comment: Please read the [tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html#granules-naming-convention) how to do that.

Comment: Sorry, this tutorial does not explain how to set a valid_from and a valid_till. It explains how to show data for 1 day.

Comment: that is the way GeoServer works! Sorry please contribute a fix if you need something else

Comment: Ok - then why is everybody posting those tutorials instead of saying - sorry, not possible so far. Thats what i am asking for.

Comment: That is what I did in the second comment. If you don't understand the basics, don't blame others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when the code was changed to support this, but the following tutorial explains how to make this work.  I tried it today and it works on GeoServer 2.19.x. Its not part of the official documentation but from my testing today it does work: https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/accessing_multidim/wxs_ranges.html

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you assign a acquisition time to each granule and encode that in the file name. GeoServer can then extract that value and apply it to the data stored. See the [tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html#granules-naming-convention) for more examples.

Comment: Yes, I am done with this tutorial - where is the time range?

Comment: Please ask a new question with the exact procedure you took and where you are stuck. GIS SE is not meant to be an online tutor and no discussion board.